# How to get the DATETIME data when I logout?

Tags: laravel, datetime

In my users table, I have a last_login, last_logout and last_ip_address. The login and ip address is now working but I don't know how to get the datetime data when the user logs out. Thanks

```
   public function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {
       $user->last_login = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
       $user->last_ip_address = $request->getClientIp();
       $user->save();
   }
```

Comment: hey, you can use Carbon::now(); to save the current date,time when the user logs out, or is active. so, `$user->last_login = Carbon::now();` Be sure to instantiate Carbon at the top of your controller, below namespace, using `use Carbon\Carbon;`

Comment: subscribe to `'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout',` and then you can use `carbon()->now()`

Comment: @UdhayanNair yes I already used the `use Carbon\Carbon`. but still it doesn't get the logout time

Comment: @shing do you have a logout event/function/service?

Answer (score 1):

The Laravel authentication system will fire events that you can listen for, like the `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout` event.

You can setup a listener that receives that event and can log the information for the user:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout;

...

public function handle(Logout $event)
{
    $user = $event->user;
    ... 
}
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Authentication - Events](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#events)

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Events - Registering Events & Listeners](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/events#registering-events-and-listeners)

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Events - Defining Listeners](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/events#defining-listeners)